# Regular expression for cn=<name>,ou=<name>,o=<bic8>,o=swift

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression to match the text entered must be of this particular format `cn=<name>,ou=<name>,o=<bic8>,o=swift` in java script

Comment: Active directory distinguished name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getMatch(str) {
  var m = /^cn=(.*?),ou=(.*?),o=(.*?),o=swift$/.exec(str);
  return (m) ? {cn:m[1], ou:m[2], o:m[3]} : null;
}
```

If the given string doesn't match it returns null, otherwise it returns an object with properties "cn", "ou", and "o" set to the values, e.g.

```
var x = getMatch("cn=foo,ou=bar,o=zip,o=swift");
alert(x.cn); // => "foo"
alert(x.ou); // => "bar"
alert(x.o);  // => "zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexp = /^[a-z]{1,2}[=]{1}[a-z0-9]+/;
```

Comment: This will match only first occurrence of token.

Comment: You've obviously never been subjected to [x509](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1422) or [ldap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#Directory_structure).